# Transference values in column on the next Date (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'), Date = c("01-Feb-17", "05-Feb-17", "01-May-17", "03-May-17","24-May-17", "05-Oct-17", "20-Oct-17", "25-Oct-17", "01-Dec-17", "12-Dec-17"), Name=c("John", "Jack", "Jack", "John", "John", "Jack", "John", "Jack", "John", "Jack"), Workout=c('150', '130', '140', '160', '150', '130', '140', '160', '150', '130'))
```

Now I want to shift values in the column Workout for every Name on the next Date.

For example:

**150** move from 01-Feb-17 (John) to 03-May-17 (John)
[image]

ect.

to value "Jack" the same action

Comment: The year in coulmn `Date` suspiciously gets values as `17` or `2017`.

Comment: @AntoniosK Oh, as 17

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'), 
                 Date = c("01-Feb-17", "05-Feb-17", "01-May-17", "03-May-17","24-May-17", "05-Oct-2017", "20-Oct-17", "25-Oct-17", "01-Dec-2017", "12-Dec-2017"), 
                 Name=c("John", "Jack", "Jack", "John", "John", "Jack", "John", "Jack", "John", "Jack"), 
                 Workout=c('150', '130', '140', '160', '150', '130', '140', '160', '150', '130'))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%                  # for every name
  mutate(Workout = lag(Workout)) %>%  # replace value with the previous one
  ungroup()                           # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#   id    Date        Name  Workout
#   <fct> <fct>       <fct> <fct>  
# 1 1     01-Feb-17   John  NA     
# 2 2     05-Feb-17   Jack  NA     
# 3 3     01-May-17   Jack  130    
# 4 4     03-May-17   John  150    
# 5 5     24-May-17   John  160    
# 6 6     05-Oct-2017 Jack  140    
# 7 7     20-Oct-17   John  150    
# 8 8     25-Oct-17   Jack  130    
# 9 9     01-Dec-2017 John  140    
#10 10    12-Dec-2017 Jack  160
```

I assume your dataset will be ordered by `Date` like in your example. If not you can order it using the `arrange` function.